# Knockout - pass attribute value from event.target as a parameter on click event

Tags: typescript, mvvm, knockout.js, parameters, click

I am experimenting with knockout events. I have three buttons ("Packers", "Trail Blazers" and "Dodgers") in a div. Each button has a data-league attribute of "NFL", "NBA", and "MLB" respectively. When I click on the div, I want the click event handler in the ViewModel to be passed in the name of the team and the league they play in directly.  What I do have working currently is getting the value from the event parameter that is supplied to the handler - but working with that event and in particular named HTML attributes directly seems in opposition to the MVVM pattern.

```
<div data-bind="click : doSomething">
  <button data-league="NFL">Packers</button>
  <button data-league="NBA">Trail Blazers</button>
  <button data-league="MLB">Dodgers</button>
</div>
<span data-bind="text:myObservable"></span>

(function() {
  window.onload = function(e) {
    try {
      var myViewModel =  {
        myObservable : ko.observable("Initial Value"),
        doSomething : (viewModel , event )=>{
          console.log("doSomething is executing")
          //How can I avoid using event.target.attributes in the viewModel code below and
          //instead have the data-league value passed in as a parameter?
          if(event.target.attributes["data-league"]){
            let league = event.target.attributes["data-league"].value
            let team = event.target.innerText
            viewModel.myObservable("The " + team + " are an " + league + " team")  
          }

        }
      }

      ko.applyBindings(myViewModel)

    } 
    catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex.toString());
    }
  }
})();
```

** EDIT - The codepen below was edited to reflect Jeff Mercado's answer and is now in TypeScript and more in the MVVM spirit **

https://codepen.io/Walkipedia/pen/jONjweq?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be applying the click event handler on the buttons themselves, rather than a parent element, for this very reason.

You should change your model to hold objects representing the teams and have your click handler use those objects.

```
const myViewModel = {
  myObservable: ko.observable("Initial Value"),
  teams: [
    { league: "NFL", team: "Packers" },
    { league: "NBA", team: "Trail Blazers" },
    { league: "MLB", team: "Dodgers" }
  ],
  doSomething: ({league, team}) => {
    console.log("doSomething is executing");
    myViewModel.myObservable(`The ${team} are an ${league} team`);
  }
};
```

```
<div data-bind="foreach: teams">
  <button data-bind="click: $root.doSomething, text: team"></button>
</div>
<span data-bind="text: myObservable"></span>
```

Comment: Perfect! That clears things up a lot and led to some new MVVM / Knockout with Typescript insights.  The linked codepen has been updated to incorporate your suggestion.